# How to list(<li>) data from a column in a table having newlines(\r +) inside ruby tag?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My code is

```
@tariff.each do |tar|  
  <li><%= tar.lt_ninety%></li>
<%end%>
```

This `lt_ninety` has a value (hey hello) contain new line`(\r +)` in between each word in table.

I have found one method in Stack Overflow, but couldn't help me to solve.

`<li><%= h(tar.lt_ninety).gsub(/\r/, '<br/>').html_safe%></li>`

and output was like

```
 <li> hey</li>
hello
```

I cannot wrap hello in `<li>`

Comment: can you post the value of `lt_ninety`?

Comment: hey\r hello are the values of lt_ninety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split `tar.lt_ninety` into separate `lines` before generating a `<li>` for each line:

```
<% @tariff.each do |tar| %>
  <% tar.lt_ninety.lines.each do |line| %>
    <li><%= line %></li>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: have tried that too. i got the value in two line which is good . but i couldn't get it inside li tag

Comment: Can you please share the HTML structure that is generated by my answer with your data.

Comment: <li> <p>hey
<br>hello</p></li> but i actually want it as <li> hey </li> <br><li>hello</li>

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your requirements. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split up `tar.lt_ninety` and loop it

```
<% @tariff.each do |tar| %> 
  <% tar.lt_ninety.split(/\r/) do |ln|%>
    <li><%= h ln %></li>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work on my code, <li><%= h ln %></li> didn't print anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Hurray!! my colleague gave me a cool solution

```
<ul><% (tar.lt_ninety).split(/\r\n/).each do |val| %>
```

`<li><%= val %></li>`

```
<% end%></ul>
```